# Powershell search CSV file with no headers and non-standard delimeter; return only certain columns in results

Tags: powershell, select, multiple-columns, delimiter, import-csv

Here is a sample line in a CSV file I have:

empcode~1~0~FirstName~LastName~Nickname~1~startdate~Supervisor~Location~Department~JobTitle~Extension

This file gets updated several times a day with new employee info and I need to be able to search for a new employee to get their employee code (empcode), First Name (FirstName), Last Name (LastName), Nickname (Nickname) and Job Title (JobTitle).

What I'm looking to do is build a powershell script to read this file and search for a user name.  Then the results I'm looking to return would look like this:

empcode FirstName LastName Nickname Department

I'm not sure if Get-Content or Import-CSV would be the way to go.  And guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: all the values you have for the sample above are also ~ delimited instead of comma delimited?

Comment: correct, they are all delimited by ~

Answer (score 3):

since i am too lazy to provide the data you didn't provide, i will skip reading the data in. you can use `Get-Content` for that. [*grin*]

what this does is ...

- gets a line from the file
- creates a header item list
- creates a list of headers to keep
- uses `ConvertFrom-Csv` with the `-Delimiter` and `-Header` parameters
- filters out anything not in the keeper list
- saves it to a $Var
- displays it on screen

the code ...

```
$InStuff = 'empcode~1~0~TheFirstName~TheLastName~TheNickname~1~startdate~Supervisor~Location~TheDepartment~JobTitle~Extension'

$Header = @'
EmpCode
1stNumber
2ndNumber
FirstName
LastName
NickName
3rdNumber
StartDate
SupervisorName
Location
Department
JobTitle
Extension
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$PropsToKeep = @(
    'FirstName'
    'LastName'
    'NickName'
    'Department'
    )

$OutStuff = $InStuff |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '~' -Header $Header |
    Select-Object -Property $PropsToKeep

$OutStuff
```

output ...

```
FirstName    LastName    NickName    Department   
---------    --------    --------    ----------   
TheFirstName TheLastName TheNickname TheDepartment
```

at that point, you can easily send the $Var to `Export-Csv` ... [*grin*]

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Please forgive my ignorance on this matter but I have one question about your code.  The CSV file doesn't have any headers and the `@InStuff` line will always be different.  Wouldn't I need to provide column numbers or even letters instead of what you have listed under `@Header` ?

Comment: @dlemley - you said it is a CSV file, that means the structure of the file will always be the same. if you want a _generic_ solution to any possible CSV structure, then please edit your Question to make that clear - AND provide two or three example lines from at least two different CSV files.

Comment: I'm not providing specific line examples because I'm protecting the employee data contained within the CSV file.  The delimited line I provided is what each line of the CSV file contains but will obviously be different for each employee.

For example; I would search for "smith" and it would return the following:
P112345~1~0~Michael~Smith~Mike~1~01/01/20~John Jones~New York~Accounting~Accountant~3320

I'd like to strip down the results so it only returns the following:

P112345 Michael Smith Mike Accountant

Comment: @dlemley - i understand sanitizing data. [*grin*] have you tried the code i posted yet? if you put the header part and the file read ahead of the actual code, it should work. ///// i am willing to test it - and provide a more realistic bit of code ... but i am not going to make up data to work with. **_if you want mpre realistic code you must provide realistic data to work on._** two or three lines of your data - sanitized data - will do the job. if you want to automate creating the headers instead of manually listing them ahead of time, then say so.

Comment: thanks for your time.  I'm not going to provide actual company data on the internet.

Comment: @dlemley - um, er, **_i did not ask for company data._** i asked for **_realistic, sanitized data_**. if you refuse to provide two or three lines of such data ... why do you expect others to do what you refuse to do?